# PostScriptTrace() gives error

Tags: r, ghostscript, postscript, r-grid

I'm having a problem using `PostScriptTrace()`from the `grImport` package in R. When I attempt to get it to create an RGML file from a simple .ps file, it fails Status 1.

The xml file does get created, but had the following content:

> Unknown device: pswrite
>
> Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
>
> Operand stack:
>       defaultdevice

The problem when I run `gswin64 -h` is that there is no available device called `pswrite`, only something called `ps2write`

So my updated question is: is it possible to either install the `pswrite` device to GhostScript or alternatively to change the `-SDEVICE` parameter called internally by `PostScriptTrace` to `ps2write` or something appropriate?

Comment: The `pswrite` device has been deprecated for some time. It outputs a bitmap rendering wrapped up in postscript. Not very portable, not very pretty. I think you can still select it if you compile from source, but I know the gs guys have been trying to get rid of it for a while.

Comment: @luserdroog thanks that's what appeared to be the case. Probably best to try and change the device in the PostScriptTrace() call.

Comment: If possible, yes, that seems like the best course for the future.